# Hostname information in the feign Logger

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign

I am using feign clients in spring-cloud environment with the `Eureka` discovery service and implementing a custom feign logger to be able to log some usefull request and response information. For that I have extended `feign.Logger` class and overriden it's methods.

So far so good, but I am interested in logging hostname the request was forwarded to. Is there a way to get this information inside the `feign.Logger`?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the `Request` from `Logger.logRequest()`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. `Request` object has `url` field, but the hostname part in that URL equals to the service name I specified in the `@FeingClient` `name` field.

Comment: Right now, I don't think there is.

Comment: Bummer.. Thank you a lot for such a quick response though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was confirmed by @spencergibb that there is no way to get hostname in the feign Logger.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear on your questions you need to get domain which request is hitting.
Then you can get it by manipulating the request.url() and get the sub string from this before uri path.